# How do I store a TfidfVectorizer for future use in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tf-idf, joblib

I have a `TfidfVectorizer` that vectorizes collection of articles followed by feature selection.

```
vectroizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectroizer.fit_transform(corpus)
selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k = 5000 )
X_train_sel = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)
```

Now, I want to store this and use it in other programs. I don't want to re-run the `TfidfVectorizer()` and the feature selector on the training dataset. How do I do that? I know how to make a model persistent using `joblib` but I wonder if this is the same as making a model persistent.

Comment: `joblib` seems working. But I guess I have to dump the vectorizer and feature selector independently.

Comment: When you get a working solution, please post your approach and some code.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html has some warnings around security and version management.

Answer (score 24):

You can simply use the built in pickle library:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("vectorizer.pickle", "wb"))
pickle.dump(selector, open("selector.pickle", "wb"))
```

and load it with:

```
vectorizer = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pickle", "rb"))
selector = pickle.load(open("selector.pickle", "rb"))
```

Pickle will serialize the objects to disk and load them in memory again when you need it

[pickle lib docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

Comment: So basically, you replaced joblib with pickle when compared your solution with mine, right?

Comment: I have tried cPickle, I have tried joblib which uses pickle.  For either approach, I get `pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: it's not found as __builtin__.instancemethod`  How does that work?  I am stroring the TfIdfVectorizer object as well.

Comment: @user2161903 he also fixed your typo in "vectroizer" ;) .

Answer (score 11):

Here is my answer using joblib:

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(vectorizer, 'vectorizer.pkl')
joblib.dump(selector, 'selector.pkl')
```

Later, I can load it and ready to go:

```
vectorizer = joblib.load('vectorizer.pkl')
selector = joblib.load('selector.pkl')

test = selector.trasnform(vectorizer.transform(['this is test']))
```

Comment: a little typo on vectorizer

Answer (score 8):

"Making an object persistent" basically means that you're going to dump the binary code stored in memory that represents the object in a file on the hard-drive, so that later on in your program or in any other program the object can be reloaded from the file in the hard drive into memory.

Either scikit-learn included `joblib` or the stdlib `pickle` and `cPickle` would do the job.
I tend to prefer `cPickle` because it is significantly faster. Using [ipython's %timeit command](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit):

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer as TFIDF
>>> t = TFIDF()
>>> t.fit_transform(['hello world'], ['this is a test'])

# generic serializer - deserializer test
>>> def dump_load_test(tfidf, serializer):
...:    with open('vectorizer.bin', 'w') as f:
...:        serializer.dump(tfidf, f)
...:    with open('vectorizer.bin', 'r') as f:
...:        return serializer.load(f)

# joblib has a slightly different interface
>>> def joblib_test(tfidf):
...:    joblib.dump(tfidf, 'tfidf.bin')
...:    return joblib.load('tfidf.bin')

# Now, time it!
>>> %timeit joblib_test(t)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.09 ms per loop

>>> %timeit dump_load_test(t, pickle)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop

>>> %timeit dump_load_test(t, cPickle)
1000 loops, best of 3: 879 µs per loop
```

Now if you want to store multiple objects in a single file, you can easily create a data structure to store them, then dump the data structure itself. This will work with `tuple`, `list` or `dict`.
From the example of your question:

```
# train
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k = 5000 )
X_train_sel = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)

# dump as a dict
data_struct = {'vectorizer': vectorizer, 'selector': selector}
# use the 'with' keyword to automatically close the file after the dump
with open('storage.bin', 'wb') as f: 
    cPickle.dump(data_struct, f)
```

Later or in another program, the following statements will bring back the data structure in your program's memory:

```
# reload
with open('storage.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data_struct = cPickle.load(f)
    vectorizer, selector = data_struct['vectorizer'], data_struct['selector']

# do stuff...
vectors = vectorizer.transform(...)
vec_sel = selector.transform(vectors)
```

Comment: Seems like the speed of pickle increase a lot. I got `%timeit dump_load_test(t, pickle) 
433 µs ± 40.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`. Also, you need to set the file open mode to `'wb'` and `'rb'`.