# NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a sentiment analyzer using scikit-learn/pandas. Building and evaluating the model works, but attempting to classify new sample text does not.

My code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

infile = 'Sentiment_Analysis_Dataset.csv'
data = "SentimentText"
labels = "Sentiment"


class Classifier():
    def __init__(self):
        self.train_set, self.test_set = self.load_data()
        self.counts, self.test_counts = self.vectorize()
        self.classifier = self.train_model()

    def load_data(self):

        df = pd.read_csv(infile, header=0, error_bad_lines=False)
        train_set, test_set = train_test_split(df, test_size=.3)
        return train_set, test_set

    def train_model(self):
        classifier = BernoulliNB()
        targets = self.train_set[labels]
        classifier.fit(self.counts, targets)
        return classifier


    def vectorize(self):

        vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                                 max_df = 0.8,
                                 sublinear_tf=True,
                                 ngram_range = (1,2),
                                 use_idf=True)
        counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(self.train_set[data])
        test_counts = vectorizer.transform(self.test_set[data])

        return counts, test_counts

    def evaluate(self):
        test_counts,test_set = self.test_counts, self.test_set
        predictions = self.classifier.predict(test_counts)
        print (classification_report(test_set[labels], predictions))
        print ("The accuracy score is {:.2%}".format(accuracy_score(test_set[labels], predictions)))


    def classify(self, input):
        input_text = input

        input_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5,
                                 max_df = 0.8,
                                 sublinear_tf=True,
                                 ngram_range = (1,2),
                                 use_idf=True)
        input_counts = input_vectorizer.transform(input_text)
        predictions = self.classifier.predict(input_counts)
        print(predictions)

myModel = Classifier()

text = ['I like this I feel good about it', 'give me 5 dollars']

myModel.classify(text)
myModel.evaluate()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment.py", line 74, in <module>
    myModel.classify(text)
  File "sentiment.py", line 66, in classify
    input_counts = input_vectorizer.transform(input_text)
  File "/home/rachel/Sentiment/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1380, in transform
    X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).transform(raw_documents)
  File "/home/rachel/Sentiment/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 890, in transform
    self._check_vocabulary()
  File "/home/rachel/Sentiment/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 278, in _check_vocabulary
    check_is_fitted(self, 'vocabulary_', msg=msg),
  File "/home/rachel/Sentiment/ENV/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 690, in check_is_fitted
    raise _NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

I'm not sure what the issue could be. In my classify method, I create a brand new vectorizer to process the text I want to classify, separate from the vectorizer used to create training and test data from the model.

Thanks

Comment: Anyway, in your `classify` function, you create a new vectorizer object, then call `transform` before it's ever been fitted.

Comment: Adding to @AryaMcCarthy 's answer, the whole classify function in this class is misleading. The constructor allows the input data to be passed. So why pass it again in classify?

Comment: Another approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764991/how-do-i-store-a-tfidfvectorizer-for-future-use-in-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've fitted a vectorizer, but you throw it away because it doesn't exist past the lifetime of your `vectorize` function. Instead, save your model in `vectorize` after it's been transformed:

```
self._vectorizer = vectorizer
```

Then in your `classify` function, don't create a new vectorizer. Instead, use the one you'd fitted to the training data:

```
input_counts = self._vectorizer.transform(input_text)
```

Comment: What if you want to come back and use it a week later though?  My first thought was to pickle the vectorizer, but one gets `can't pickle instancemethod objects`.  So how can one save vectorizer for longer term storage?

Comment: You should really post that as a separate question, so it gets greater visibility. Link to this one if needed.

Answer (score 10):

Save `vectorizer` as a `pickle` or `joblib` file and load it when you want to predict.

```
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("vectorizer.pickle", "wb")) //Save vectorizer
pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pickle", 'rb'))     // Load vectorizer
```

Comment: You saved the day!

Answer (score 7):

You can save both the model and the vectorizer and use them later on as well: here is how I did it:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
import pickle


# Train the classification model
def train_model():
    df = pd.read_json('intent_data.json')

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Utterance'], df['Intent'], random_state=0)

    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

    model = LinearSVC().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)

    # Save the vectorizer
    vec_file = 'vectorizer.pickle'
    pickle.dump(count_vect, open(vec_file, 'wb'))

    # Save the model
    mod_file = 'classification.model'
    pickle.dump(model, open(mod_file, 'wb'))


# Load the classification model from disk and use for predictions
def classify_utterance(utt):
    # load the vectorizer
    loaded_vectorizer = pickle.load(open('vectorizer.pickle', 'rb'))

    # load the model
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open('classification.model', 'rb'))

    # make a prediction
    print(loaded_model.predict(loaded_vectorizer.transform([utt])))
```