# Storing TfidfVectorizer for future use

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need to store a TfidfVectorizer for future use. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764991/how-do-i-store-a-tfidfvectorizer-for-future-use-in-scikit-learn), I did below -

```
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', max_features=5000)
pickle.dump(tfidf_vect, open("vectorizer.pickle", "wb"))
```

Then on a separate flask service, I do below

```
@app.route('/cuisine/api/json',methods=['POST'])
def getCuisine():
    content=jsonify(request.json)
    test = pd.io.json.json_normalize(request.json)
    tfidf_vect = pickle.load(open("vectorizer.pickle", "rb"))
    test['ingredients'] = [str(map(makeString, x)) for x in test['ingredients']]
    test_transform = tfidf_vect.transform(test['ingredients'].values)
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    X_test = test_transform
    y_test = le.fit_transform(test['cuisine'].values)
```

But I am getting below error

```
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
```

Not sure what m I missing. Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to fit your model first:

```
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern=r'\w{1,}', max_features=5000)
tfidf_vect.fit() <-- pass your training data!
pickle.dump(tfidf_vect, open("vectorizer.pickle", "wb"))
```